# Optimizing weights in logistic regression ( log likelihood )

Tags: machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression, supervised-learning, log-likelihood

In Logistic Regression:

hypothesis function,

```
                   h(x) = ( 1 + exp{-wx} )^-1
```

where,        w - weights/parameters to be fit or optimized

---

Cost function ( -ve log likelihood function ) is given as :

For a single training e.g.. (x,y):

```
         l(w) = y * log ( h(x) ) + (1 - y) * log ( 1 - h(x) )
```

The goal is to maximize l(w) over all the training examples and thereby estimate w.

---

Question :

Consider the situation wherein there are many more positive (y=1) training examples than negative (y=0) training examples.

For simplicity:

if we consider only the positive (y=1) examples:
Algorithm runs:

```
           maximize ( l(w) )

          =>  maximize ( y * log ( h(x) ) )

          =>  maximize ( log( h(x) ) )

          =>  maximize ( h(x) ); since log(z) increases with z

          =>  maximize ( ( 1 + exp{-wx} )^-1 )

          =>  maximize ( wx );   
   since a larger wx will increase h(x) and move it closer to 1
```

In other words, the optimization algorithm will try to increase (wx) so as to better fit the data and increase likelihood.

---

However, it seems possible that there is an unintended way for the algorithm to increase (wx) but not improve the solution ( decision boundary ) in anyway :

```
             by scaling w: w' = k*w  ( where k is positive constant )
```

We can increase (k*wx) without changing our solution in anyway.

1)  Why is this not a problem ? Or is this a problem ?

2)  One can argue that in a dataset with many more positive examples than negative examples, the algorithm will try to keep increasing the ||w||.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is a problem sometimes, but it is solved by regularization
2. Only if the classes are perfectly separated

If **there are only y=1**, algorithm will indeed try to make `wx` as large as possible, and **never converge**. But if you have only one class, you don't need logistic regression at all.

If **the dataset is imbalanced** (there are much more y=1 than y=0), **in general**, logistic regression would suffer **no convergence problems**.

Let's see why. Suppose you have only 1 negative example `x_0`, and N identical positive examples `x_1`. Then log-likelihood would look like

```
l(w) = N * log(h(x_1)) + log(1-h(x_0))
```

The `h(x)` is bounded between 0 and 1, so the both components are bounded above by 0, but unbounded from below.

Now, if `w` is large enough and you keep increasing it, the first term will increase only marginally (because it is already close to 0), but the second term can decrease very fast (because `log(x)` tends to minus infinity very fast when `x` approaches 0). If you increase `w` unlimitely, `l(w)` will go to minus infinity. Thus, **there is a finite `w` that maximizes likelihood**.

But there is one important **exception**. It happens when the classes are **perfectly separated** by some hyperplane (it has **little to do with class sizes**). In this case, both the first and the second term will tend to `0` while `||w||` tends to infinity.

But if the classes are perfectly separated, you probably don't need logistic regression at all! Its power is in the probabilistic prediction, but in the perfeclty-separated case, prediction might be deterministic! So you could apply, say, an SVM to your data instead.

Or you can solve a regularized problem, maximizing `l(w)-lambda*||w||`. For example, in scikit-learn logistic regression [does exactly this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248587/confusing-results-with-logistic-regression-in-python/47248936#47248936). In this case, if `l(w)` is sufficiently close to 0, `||w||` will dominate and the objective function will eventually decrease in `w`.

Thus, a small penalty in the objective function solves are you worries. And this is a widely applied solution, not only in logistic regression, but in linear models (Lasso, Ridge, etc.) and in neural networks.